# Does copying a bitmap in place leak memory?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, bitmap

I'm curious if the following code will leak...

```
    data = getBitmapdataFromCameraCallback();//this is immutable, so...
    //make a mutable copy...
    originalUserPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // -1 doesn't reverse it for some oddball reason, so, we get REALLY close to -1
    matrix.preScale(-0.999f, 1.0f);//don't ask don't tell

     originalUserPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalUserPhoto, 0, 0,
          originalUserPhoto.getWidth(), originalUserPhoto.getHeight(),    
          matrix, true);
```

If I'm modifying the originalUserPhoto in place (notice I'm passing it in as the source of createBitmap), does that leak the original data? Or is the JVM smart enough to release the data that was there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. You have two Bitmap objects (the first one created by decodeByteArray, the second one by createBitmap), and the first one has nothing referencing it, so during a future garbage collection cycle, it is likely to get deleted.

That said, while the native backing store for the bitmap will be deleted too when the Bitmap is recycled, I would recommend manually deleting the first bitmap after you're done using it -  keep it in a separate reference and call `recycle()` on it. Bitmaps can be very expensive.

Btw, if the point of your createBitmap is just to scale, I would consider scaling the original bitmap down as you decode it by passing in options. You won't be able to scale to exactly that size you want, but at least you won't end up with an unwieldly huge bitmap that you'll scale down to a tenth of its size. That will be faster and avoid a memory spike.

Comment: Very interesting... just to be clear, you're saying that creating a copy of bitmapA, using bitmapA as the source and spitting back out to bitmapA, doesn't leak the bytes that were originally in bitmapA? or are you saying that in THIS case it won't because the contents of the original happen to be the byte data from the camera which are going to get released natively by the camera when all references to that data are gone? My understanding is that Bitmap data doesn't natively get collected, unless you expressly set it to null.

Comment: Memory won't leak, period. Java doesn't "lose" things like C++ would if you stop tracking a pointer. It will be aware that there are two Bitmap objects, and it will eventually delete the one that's been abandoned. There is no connection between the two bitmaps, you created one using the other, but once the creation process is complete, there will be no link between the two of them whatsoever, so each one has its own (expensive) chunk of memory.

Comment: I beg to differ.  Look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html and I've ready numerous articles in the past talking about how Bitmaps need to be released manually in order not to leak... granted it's not like C, but it's similar (and arguably worse since there's nothing you can do to FORCE it to release the memory! :)

Comment: You misread that article. They're specifically talking about situations where there is still a REFERENCE to the bitmap. In your case, there isn't. In their case, it's due to a `static` member, which means that it will stick around forever.

Comment: well, I think my confusion is related to the fact that I'm witnessing a really brutal OUT OF MEMORY exception that is happening intermittently, from time to time, over the course of several runnings of my application, even though I have no static references (that I know of) to anything, so, clearly memory isn't being de-allocated correctly, but I'm stumped as to where... hence my question about this particular maneuver, in this question. The image is being stored in a Bitmap I keep in the Application and I'm worried that that's somehow messing things up, but I don't know why it would.

Comment: Again, I would recommend calling recycle() on a bitmap once you don't need it anymore. Also, if you're using a debugger, bitmaps are known to leak. And finally, even though the garbage collection will eventually free up memory, things are a bit more complicated since the bulk of the Bitmap's memory is native. But there isn't really a "leak" per se, not unless you keep that second bitmap around forever and keep creating new ones. Given the fragment of code you sent, it should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm calling recycle on everything like a feind. In any event, I appreciate your help... I'll go looking for the problem elsewhere.